# Merging entities - Enterprise Architect

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect, sequence-diagram

I have a problem, how can I "merge" entities on sequence diagram in Enterprise Architect (red circle), to that they make one long bar from the top to the end of lifeline?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create the same diagram and in my version of EA (10.0...) the lifeline is "merged" :) Also I am not able to achieve, that lifeline for Cart Item starts in the middle of the diagram, as yours does. For me, all lifelines are aligned to top and I can't change that.

What version of EA are you using? I don't know about any settings impacting this, must be some kind of bug/intended functionality.

The only suggestion I have is that you try to redraw the diagram from scratch.

Comment: I am using v9.3. If you're saying that in 10.0 it works as I want it to work, I'll try that ;) thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the `getCart` message open the context menu and choose `Activation/Extend Source Activation Down`.

**Edit** I just verified with 9.3.

From [image]

via [image]

you get [image]

Comment: which version of EA do you use?

Comment: I am using version 9.3

Comment: See my edit. If that does not work follow the advice from @trueanalysis.eu and create the diagram new. You can try to use `Copy Diagram/Paste Diagram (Deep)` from the broswer.